# C program not writing to text file

Tags: c, text-files

So here is the problem:

*I want to write some text to a **text file**, but I got across some weird situations:*

### SAMPLE 1:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("structures.txt", "a+"); // open the file for reading & writing
    int choice = 0;

    if(file == NULL)
        puts("Unable to open text file");
    else { 
        do {
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            fprintf(file, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
        }while(choice > 0);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

In this version of the program, nothing ever gets written to the text file & I can't understand why. But the strangest thing for me is next:

### SAMPLE 2:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("structures.txt", "a+"); // open the file for reading & writing
    int choice = 0;

    if(file == NULL)
        puts("Unable to open text file");
    else { 
        do {
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            fprintf(file, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
            fclose(file); // Added this line, the writing works
        }while(choice > 0);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

After adding `fclose(file);` directly after the `fprintf` call, the program successfully writes :

> This is testing for fprintf...

to the text file.

My questions are:

- Does that mean that I have to open my text file whenever I want to
  write some text to it & close it directly afterwards ?
- Does `fclose()` has anything to do with the **writing** process ?
- What are the factors that prevent `fprintf()` from working ?
  (1st sample)
- How can I open & close the text file just ONCE, at the start of the program & at the end of it (respectively) guaranteeing at the same time that my program will work flawlessly ?

Comment: In the first snippet, try replacing `fprintf` with `printf`. Will it work with the same input (btw, what is it?)?

Comment: I did, but nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: So the problem with your input. Debug it. Nothing to do with file IO

Comment: I type in regular integers (1, 2, 5). I debugged, & I couldn't see anything that mattered.

Comment: So you see the debugger stepping over `printf` but doesn't print anything? Hard to believe..

Comment: Compiled with MSVC, your program sample 1 produced a file with the message you write (but not the input value, as coded). Did you `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: @WeatherVane actually I haven't been including `<stdio.h>` but still, same old behavior. (I'm using DevC++'s TDM-GCC compiler)

Comment: Perhaps then it is time to go away for 5 minutes, come back, delete all the old files, compile and try again.

Comment: OK I'll give it a try.

Comment: @WeatherVane What is the name of this technique? Using it intuitively, but would like to formalize :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. we used to call it "finger trouble".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using `int fflush (FILE *stream)` (which @Jonathan hinted at).

> Flushing output on a buffered stream means transmitting all
>   accumulated characters to the file. There are many circumstances when
>   buffered output on a stream is flushed automatically:
>
> **When you try to do output and the output buffer is full.**
>
> **When the stream is closed.**
>
> **When the program terminates by calling exit.**
>
> **When a newline is written, if the stream is line buffered.**
>
> **Whenever an input operation on any stream actually reads data from its file.**

So basically, I just had to call `fflush()` after the call to `fprintf()` :

```
fprintf(file, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
fflush(file);
```

Answer (score 4):

> Does that mean that I have to open my text file whenever I want to write some text to it & close it directly afterwards ?

No, but it may mean you need to close the file before the contents you've written will actually be flushed and written out to the file.

> Does fclose() has anything to do with the writing process ?

Most file streams are buffered. Meaning that each write goes to memory. It is not written to disk until the buffer is full or you call close.

> What are the factors that prevent fprintf() from working ? (1st sample)

Anything you get significantly wrong.

> How can I open & close the text file just ONCE, at the start of the program & at the end of it (respectively) guaranteeing at the same time that my program will work flawlessly ?

You could call something like `fflush()`. But are you sure you tried this and the file contained nothing even after you finally closed the file at the end?

Comment: Should I empty the text file & USE `flush()` or just empty it ?

Comment: Typo: it is `fflush` with two letters `f`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Not sure what you mean by *empty the text file*. Either way, run the program as is to completion. Are you sure the file is still empty after it terminates?